# How to set a ssh tunnel properly

Tags: networking, ssh

Suppose, I've got a computer in my home network running Ubuntu and Glassfish Application Server. I'm debugging my web application on it using WiFi. Next step would be uploading some sensitive data. I'm worrying about security of the WiFi. I don't want to overcomplicate this setup nor lose comfort of my WiFi. So, I've decided to bind Glassfish's listener to ::1 and forward server's port 8080 to my laptop using ssh tunnel.

`wget localhost:8080/` is working as expected, downloading root index.html

Remote access to port 8080 of my server isn't working - as expected.

```
ssh -L 8080:homeserver:8080 minorthreat@homeserver - channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
```

doesn't work. I don't know why.

UPD:

- I get the ssh connection to the remote server, so the credentials are
  ok, I suppose. I don't see a reason to put -vvv listing, but i'm
  including this anyway just for a case.
- I've noticed that ssh can't register known_hosts for some reason, but
  it's a different problem with lower priority. I'll make it work using
  cert-based auth in near future
- This tunnel worked when glassfish's listener was bound to 0.0.0.0.
  Alas, it's not ok, I want to forbid any connection to the server
  except those coming from ssh tunnel (mine connections from laptop).
- The problem is that It doesn't forward connection laptop[localhost
  interface]:8080->homeserver[::1 interface]:8080

  ```
  OpenSSH_5.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0 29 Mar 2010
  debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
  debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
  debug1: Connecting to homeserver [192.168.1.101] port 22.
  debug1: Connection established.
  Could not create directory '/home/mt/.ssh'.
  debug1: identity file /home/mt/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
  debug1: identity file /home/mt/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
  debug1: identity file /home/mt/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
  debug1: identity file /home/mt/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
  debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
  debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2 pat OpenSSH*
  debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
  debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.4
  debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  /..... skip encryption details to fit char limits ........./
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
  debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1
  debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
  debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1
  debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<2048<8192) sent
  debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
  debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 181/320
  debug2: bits set: 1066/2048
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
  debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
  debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host homeserver filename /home/mt/.ssh/known_hosts
  debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host homeserver filename /home/mt/.ssh/known_hosts
  debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host homeserver filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
  debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host homeserver filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
  debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host 192.168.1.101 filename /home/mt/.ssh/known_hosts
  debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host 192.168.1.101 filename /home/mt/.ssh/known_hosts
  debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host 192.168.1.101 filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
  debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host 192.168.1.101 filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
  debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host homeserver filename /home/mt/.ssh/known_hosts
  debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host homeserver filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
  debug2: no key of type 0 for host homeserver
  debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host homeserver filename /home/mt/.ssh/known_hosts2
  debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host homeserver filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2
  debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host homeserver filename /home/mt/.ssh/known_hosts
  debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host homeserver filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
  debug2: no key of type 2 for host homeserver
  The authenticity of host 'homeserver (192.168.1.101)' can't be established.                                                                                                                                                                      
  RSA key fingerprint is 45:84:58:01:80:95:bb:71:0e:a3:66:2f:e6:cd:e9:34.
  Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
  Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/home/mt/.ssh/known_hosts).
  debug2: bits set: 1010/2048
  debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
  debug2: kex_derive_keys
  debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
  debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
  debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
  debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
  debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
  debug2: key: /home/mt/.ssh/id_rsa (0x0)
  debug2: key: /home/mt/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0)
  debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
  debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
  debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
  debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
  debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
  debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
  debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
  debug1: Trying private key: /home/mt/.ssh/id_rsa
  debug3: no such identity: /home/mt/.ssh/id_rsa
  debug1: Trying private key: /home/mt/.ssh/id_dsa
  debug3: no such identity: /home/mt/.ssh/id_dsa
  debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
  debug3: authmethod_lookup password
  debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
  debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
  debug1: Next authentication method: password
  minorthreat@homeserver's password:                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  debug3: packet_send2: adding 48 (len 63 padlen 17 extra_pad 64)
  debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
  debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
  debug1: Local connections to localhost:8080 forwarded to remote address homeserver:8080
  debug3: channel_setup_fwd_listener: type 2 wildcard 0 addr NULL
  debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 8080.
  debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
  debug3: fd 4 is O_NONBLOCK
  debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
  debug1: channel 1: new [client-session]
  debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 1
  debug2: channel 1: send open
  debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
  debug1: Entering interactive session.
  debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
  debug2: callback start
  debug2: client_session2_setup: id 1
  debug2: channel 1: request pty-req confirm 1
  debug2: channel 1: request shell confirm 1
  debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
  debug2: callback done
  debug2: channel 1: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
  debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 1
  debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 1
  debug2: channel 1: rcvd adjust 2097152
  debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 1
  debug2: shell request accepted on channel 1
  Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-91-generic x86_64)
  ```

Comment: Can you post the output of `ssh -vvv minorthreat@homeserver`

Comment: Updated post for you

Comment: Try `ssh -f minorthreat@homeserver -L 8080:homeserver:8080 -N` -f tells ssh to run in background and -N not to run any commands remote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're telling SSH to connect to (forward connections to) homeserver:8080 on the remote end, but your glassfish isn't bound to that IP; it's bound to localhost.

Try `ssh -L 8080:localhost:8080 minorthreat@homeserver`.

Comment: However, I've decided to spend some time tuning up openvpn server and binding all java and postgres endpoints to the tap0 interface. Much more convenient this way. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: Be aware, though, that this makes them addressable on the local network(s) your server is on. E.g. if your tap0 has `192.168.42.42/24`, and your eth0 interface has `10.1.1.1/24`, then someone on the `10.1.1.0/24` network who knows about your `192.168.42.42` address can send packets from e.g. `10.1.1.2`, addressed to `192.168.42.42` in the IP layer and to your eth0's MAC address, and your Linux box will receive them and reply to them. This doesn't need any complicated coding on the client; they just need to add a route via `10.1.1.1` towards `192.168.42.42`.

Comment: So, binding services to a tap0 interface doesn't "hide" them as thoroughly as binding them to a loopback address.

Comment: How could this be? I haven't configured my Linux as a router. Why should it forward packets from one interface to another?

Comment: $ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

0

Comment: It's not "forwarding" unless the packet is actually sent out on another interface. Try it if you don't believe me. :)

Comment: And what if i change this to tun type? Can it fix that?

Comment: No. If your box has an IP of `192.168.42.42` on any interface, it will by default accept packets to that IP on all interfaces, and reply to them. You have to go out of your way to prevent it (e.g. by setting up netfilter rules).

Comment: Ok then, I'll try to configure my firewall then. And how you would solve problem like mine? Binding to localhost wasn't really an option, there's lots of ports there including java EE protos, JVM remote debug (I need this), postgres (I need this too), etc etc.

Comment: I honestly don't see why binding to localhost is not an option (you can script the SSH portforwarding so that it's not so inconvenient), but you should have firewall rules in any case to avoid inadvertently exposing internal services.